# Disable custom field validation

Tags: development, joomla-4.x, custom-field

I've created a new custom field type name "lazyload" on Joomla 4.

Basically it is a list field that places an empty (no options) HTML select tag and uses the [select2](https://select2.org/) plugin to fetch the options via ajax (this is necessary because some fields can have as much as 7000+ options).

I'm using it on articles and everything is working fine apart from the moment I save the article: it returns "Invalid field: [field name]" and it does not store the selected values.

Of course this is because a safety good practice: saved results must be validated against existing options, but how can I disable this validation? - or, better still, create my own validation rules?

Comment: The validation rules for a field are determined by the attributes. If it's validating against options, then there's probably an entry for validate="options" in the form's XML definition. Remove that attribute and it should stop trying to validate the options.
If you want to create your own validation rules have a look at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Server-side_form_validation. It's the J3 version, but it's a good starting point

Comment: @MattGarrod I did add $fieldNode->setAttribute('validate', '') and it removed validation.
Still struggling on how to create the rules: documentation is for J3 and not quite clear on how to create the rules for a field plugin on J4 :(

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about creating validation rules for use in custom field plugins. The rule itself is a loose class file and the plugin does not interact with it on its own. To use it, you have to set the `validate` attribute on the field element in the form. You're already aware that in a custom field plugin this is done by manipulating the field node in `onCustomFieldsPrepareDom` event:

```
public function onCustomFieldsPrepareDom($field, DOMElement $parent, Form $form)
{
    $fieldNode = parent::onCustomFieldsPrepareDom($field, $parent, $form);
    $fieldNode->setAttribute('addrulepath', 'plugins/fields/mylist/rule');
    $fieldNode->setAttribute('validate', 'my.test');

    return $fieldNode;
}
```

The code above loads `MyFormRuleTest` rule class located in `plugins/fields/mylist/rule/test.php` file. If your plugin uses namespaced classes, use `addruleprefix` attribute instead:

```
$fieldNode->setAttribute('addruleprefix', 'My\\Plugin\\Fields\\MyList\\Rule');
$fieldNode->setAttribute('validate', 'Test');
```

This code would load `My\Plugin\Fields\MyList\Rule\TestRule` class.